# проблема в строках

Tags: php

Ещё раз здравствуйте. C наступающим праздником "День программиста"!
У меня такая проблема: вот 2 строки, например:

```
|имя   | |фамилия   | |год рождения|
 Роман    Самойлов     1990
 Виктор   Кажемякин    1989  
...       .....       .... и тд
```

Их надо занести в базу.
Но границ нету между ними. И имена, и фамилии разного количества букв. Ориентироваться только можно на | . Но палочка только сверху. Надеюсь, я правильно всё растолковал!

Comment: проблема не в строках ;) ... и много у тебя таких строк? каждая строка это имя фамилия и год?

Comment: разделение по пробелу и все

Comment: строк много! там и номер счёта они разные по обьёму цифр! какой функцией??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну если предположиь, что это таблица, делаем так:

```
<?
$text = <<<TEXT
|имя   | |фамилия   | |год рождения|
 Роман    Самойлов     1990
 Виктор   Кажемякин    1989  
TEXT;
// $text = file_get_contents('myfile.txt');
$fields = array();
$strings = explode("\n", $text);
$header = explode('| |', $strings[0]);
for ($i = 1; $i < count($strings); $i++) {
  if (!trim($strings[$i])) continue;
  $f = array();
  $pos = 1;
  foreach ($header as $str) {
    $f[] = trim(substr($strings[$i], $pos, strlen($str)+3));
    $pos += strlen($str)+3;
    }
  if (!empty($f))
    $fields[$i] = $f;
  }
echo '<pre>';
print_r($fields);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Собственно, он рабочий, можете запустить и править.

Answer (score 1):

подгружаете по строке и обрабатываете

```
function razboy($stroka){
$st=explode (" ",$stroka);
$name=trim($st[0]);
$fam=trim($st[1]);
$date=trim($st[2]);
//далее записываете в базу строку

return;
}
```

// а тут загрузка файла и по строкам направлять в функцию котоорая выше

Comment: спасибо на хлеб не намажешь)) надо нажимать на спасибо))

Comment: тут ещё например:
|номер договора|кредит договор| |номер кредита|
 10020304                          456855
кредитный договор пуст! он же может записать в крдитный договор номер кредита

Comment: если у вас между именем, фамилией и годом разные количества пробелов то советую использовать код от товарища knes

Comment: можно спросить в каком виде у вас данные? в текстовом файлике записаны такой таблицей или в чем?

Comment: да! в текстовом!

Comment: Мне кажется надо ориентироватся на | ! палочки! вот тока как?(

Comment: Сломается это при

    |foo      | |bar  | |baz  |
     abcd efg    lol     123

У @Sh4dow более корректный вариант — разбирает первую строку и запоминает диапазоны.

Answer (score 0):

1) Предполагаем, что фамилии все состоят либо из одного слова, либо записываются согласно правилам двойных имен/фамилий:

```
preg_match_all("/\s*([-а-яА-Я]+)\s*([-а-яА-Я]+)\s*(\d{4})\s*/",$str,$matches);
//$matches[1] - Имя - массив всех имен
//$matches[2][0] - Фамилия - массив всех фамилий
//$matches[3][0] - год рождения - массив всех лет
```

Comment: тут ещё например:
|номер договора|кредит договор| |номер кредита|
 10020304                          456855
кредитный договор пуст! он же может записать в крдитный договор номер кредита

Answer (score 0):

Можно также юзать функцию [file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Она зачитывает файл в массив строк из которых он состоит. Ну а дальше уже в цикле применяем к каждой строке explode() и таким получаем нужные данные.